# VB.Net WebBrowser invoke javascript function is not working

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a VB.Net windows application project.

This is the VB.Net code snippet below.

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

     'webBrowser1 is the variable of the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser class. 
        webBrowser1.Navigate("file:///" & IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\test.html"))

        'not working
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("test")
```

This is the test.html code snippet below.

```
<html>
<title>test</title>
<body>
<script>
    function test(){
        alert('test');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This application won't popup the 'test' alert in the javascript test function.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: I usually use this to call scripts: `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "RunScriptRun", "<script> test();</script>")`. Let me know if it's applicable in your case.

Comment: @AllenBinuya : That works only in ASP.NET, not WinForms.

Comment: Ohh.. I'm sorry, I can't differentiate WinFoms and ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I already know the problem.After moving InvokeScript function to button_click function,it's working.So this is call timing problem

Comment: Ah, of course. Yes, you must give the page a chance to load. If you want to execute something after loading the page you can use the [**`DocumentCompleted`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event. It is raised when the web browser has finished loading the page.